# docker: OCI runtime create failed: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []string: unknown

Tags: debian, docker, astra-linux

Я получил эту ошибку после обновления Docker на Linux Astra (основана на Debian) при попытке выполнить `sudo docker run hello-world`.

Полный текст ошибки:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []string: unknown.
```

`sudo docker -v` возвращает `Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**У нас была такая же проблема помогло переход на docker-ce**

Нам пришлось удалить все и поставить заново

Далее последовательность наших действий

 Удаление

```
dpkg -l | grep -i docker

sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce  
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
```

Установка

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   jessie \
   stable"

pt-get update

sudo apt-get install docker-ce

sudo apt-get install docker-ce-cli
```

У нас после этого заработало

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая подборка по настройке docker на астра линуксе

https://entnet.ru/server/dokerizatsiya.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]